# How to mock/simulate in the jest test PubNub event which added in pubnub.addListener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, pubnub

I have a package that uses PubNub, I', try to cover all package files with jest tests, but I have a problem: I can't find the way to cover events inside the listener

```
    // add listener
    const listener = {
        // Need to cover these cases (status and message)
        status: (statusEvent) => {
            if (statusEvent.category === "PNConnectedCategory") {
                console.log("Connected");
            }
        },
        message: (messageEvent) => {
            // Process message
        }
    };

    this.pubnub.addListener(listener);

    this.pubnub.subscribe({
        channels: [this.channel]
    });
```

I attached a screen with the part which I need to cover test
[![uncovered file part][1]][1]
How to mock/simulate in the jest test  PubNub event which added in pubnub.addListener?

```
describe("publishPubNub test suites", () => {  
        const sideEffect = function (options) {
            pubnubService.publishPubNub(options);
            return true;
        } 

        it("successfull", () => {
            //TODO: mock event here
            const isCompleted =  sideEffect(publishPubNubOptions)
            expect(isCompleted).toBeTruthy();
        });
    })
```

Thanks for any helps or advice.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF3c2.png

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cover events inside the listener". What are you looking to do here? In other words, I am unclear what the actual challenge is here. Do you have an example of "covering other things successfully"? Trying to understand if this is specific to PubNub SDK or just a general challenge for async test coverage.

Comment: @CraigConover Hi, in the attached screen I have highlighted lines in red color, it's lines which not covered in the test for now, as a final result I need to cover them. Here I'm not sure how to do it. In normal usage in project, I go to this part after PubNub subscribe action(in debug mode fall to listener->status), but in test mode, I'm not fall to listener-> status. Here I need some mock to cover this part in the test, or some simulation to fall into this method and as a final result, I will get covered test.

Comment: Hmm, i think this might be more of a Jest expert question than PubNub so I do not have any insights. Asking internally if anyone else at PN can assist.

Answer (score 1):

The listener status handler will be invoked whenever a connection is established (or some other connection event happens).  The message handler will be invoked whenever your application receives a message that it has previously subscribed to.

You could either:

1. Test your application against a real PubNub instance, though that would require an Internet connection.
2. Create a mocked library.  PubNub does not offer an official mocked library so you would need to roll your own.  Something like the following based on your image:

```js
'use strict';
class PubNub {
    constructor(pubKey, subKey, uniqueId) {
        this.listener = {}
    }
    addListener(listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    subscribe(channelsObj) {
        this.listener.status({"category": "PNConnectedCategory"})
    }
    publishPubNub(options) {
        this.listener.message({"message": {"request": {"decision": "approved"}}})
    }
}
module.exports = PubNub;
```